# Why does the colorful background not cover my page completely when I scale down the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a webpage with dynamic change to gradient in the background.

There are two columns - one contains a photo of a phone, the other one - some text. When the webpage is on full screen, it looks as I want - the gradient layer covers the whole background (stretched to width/height) and photo is next to the text:

[image]

But when I scale down the webpage horizontally, the text goes under the image (which is fine), but the gradient does not cover the whole page, as seen here:

[image]

Here's the complete jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/cj37qamw/

I have - in the `css` stylesheet - the following code:

```
#gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

so I thought it should work - but it doesn't.

Can you help me and tell why it doesn't work as it should?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve but removing the `height: 100vh;` will allow the gradient to vertically extend.

Comment: @AndreiV but if I remove `height` then when user enters the page, he sees http://i.imgur.com/RqmjI0V.png- as you see the gradient is not stretched vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGED ANSWER AFTER COMMENTS:

It seems I found the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xh7L4rvt/1/

1.) I changed the selector in the Javascript so that the gradient is applied to `body` instead of `#gradient`.

2.) In the CSS I changed this:

```
html,
body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and

```
#gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however the problem is that now when the page is on the full screen, the gradient does not cover the whole page vertically, as seen here http://i.imgur.com/RqmjI0V.png , that's why I was using height 100vh to display it stretched vertically too

Comment: I added `min-height` to `body`, but it didn't change the effect, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/jzaj8L40/2/ as you see in the result: http://i.imgur.com/WXHWP0w.png

Comment: please note my changed answer and new fiddle

Comment: now it works, thank you very much for the change, I just have one more question - I wanted to avoid attaching it to the `body`, because I plan to add another white section on the bottom, visible when user scrolls down the screen. Therefore I wanted to attach it to `gradient` div. What I want to achieve is that: when user opens the page, he sees the gradient on the whole screen, and when he scrolls down, there's white section with some other content. Is it achievable with your current solution?

Comment: well, you should have said that before (and provided that code)... That's closer to the previous solution I had, I would develop it from there. Probably with `min-height: 100%` for the `#gradient` element, but that depends on the actual situation.

Comment: Johannes, I will accept this answer since it's completely fulfilling my question, I will try to cope with the rest of the code and if I fail, I will ask another question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add the html and body tag to have the same width and height as your #gradient ID:

> ```
> html,
> body,
> #gradient {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: vh%;
> }
> ```

```js
var colors = new Array(
  [62,35,255],
  [60,255,60],
  [255,35,98],
  [45,175,230],
  [255,0,255],
  [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{
  
  if ( $===undefined ) return;
  
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

 $('#gradient').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
  
  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
    
    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    
  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}

/*
* Cover
*/

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}

#gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: vh%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { /* change max with to your needings */
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: vh%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="gradient">

  <div class="site-wrapper">

    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

      <div class="cover-container">

  

        <div class="inner cover">
          <div class="col-md-6">       
              <img src="http://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/apple-iphone6-gold-portrait.png" class="img-responsive">             
          </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
             <div class="description">
    <h4>header</h4>
     <p>test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text </p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT: added media query.

Comment: this solution works only when the window is small, when I expand it to full screen I see that the gradient does not fill the whole window

Comment: @user3766930 You can fix that with media queries. I edited the code.